# Доступ к локальному серверу на компьютере через телефон

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер

Я написал небольшое приложение на flask и запустил локальный сервер на компьютере.
адрес 127.0.0.1:5000
Есть сеть WI-FI к которой подключен телефон. Как можно зайти на сайт с телефона?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` - это не адрес, а аналог местоимения "Я". Узнайте реальный адрес компьютера в сети wifi

Answer (score 2):

Вместо 127.0.0.1 укажи то число, которое ему было выдано при подключении к сети (например: 192.168.0.102:5000), и по нему и обращайся с любого другого устройства, подключенного к той же сети.

Answer (score 1):

Локальный IP-адрес выдаётся устройству роутером при подключении. Вы можете в настройках роутера сделать его статичным, привязав к мак-адресу (см. скриншот). Чтобы узнать локальный адрес через терминал, можно воспользоваться командой `ip addr`.

[image: скриншот]

На самом деле я не совсем понимаю, зачем вам так нужен локальный адрес. Если проблем с доступом к интернету нет, то можете зайти с телефона и по внешнему айпи, который можно посмотреть на любом сайте вроде https://2ip.ru. Кстати, на подобном украинском сайте отображается не только внешний, но также и локальный адрес - https://2ip.ua.

Comment: То есть в телефоне в адресной строке просто указать внешний айпи? или нужно что-то еще

Comment: @ВикторМорозов айпи:порт

Comment: Далеко не все провайдеры предоставляют "белые" IP-адреса.

Answer (score -1):

с помощью сервиса [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com) можно сделать так чтобы на ссылку с локального хоста (например: localhost:5000) можно было заходить с любого устройства
если у тебя linux стоит, то все просто:
1. зайди на сайт [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com), зарегистрируйся
2. скачай саму программу, разархивируй в удобное место и запусти оттуда терминал
3. запусти flask приложение
4. введи `./ngrok authtoken <твой токен>`, а затем `./ngrok http 5000`(если у тебя порт на локалхосте 5000)